# Order object_list with django-profiles

Tags: django, django-profiles

Using the django-profiles app, I want to display the users' profiles in an ordered list.
Ordered by different fields, depending on the situation.

Now the docs say something about passing extra arguments to the views [here](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/src/c21962558420/docs/views.txt) but I don't know how to do that, since the urls are just included (as opposed by defined by myself).

So,**how can I pass in the "order_by" part that I can just use in the normal list view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the code [1], there is no way to alter the queryset in the way you want.

Your best option is probably to write this view yourself, using the existing implementation as a guide if you like (e.g. you can still call object_list when you've got a queryset ordered to your specification).  Then either override the profile list URL in your own `urls.py` by declaring it first:

```
...
url(r'^profiles/$', path.to.my_profile_list_view, name='my_profile_list'), 

(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
...
```

or create a new URL for this and use that on your site instead:

```
url(r'^ordered-profiles/$', path.to.my_profile_list_view, name='my_profile_list'),
```

[1] https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/src/c21962558420/profiles/views.py#cl-287

See also: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/src/c21962558420/profiles/urls.py